# Что-то не нравиться в ctx.send('не спамь')

Tags: python, discord.py

````
from discord.ext import commands
import datetime
import time


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Бот готов')


# выдача обычной роли
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    standart_channel = client.get_channel(912753884068479029)
    standart_role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id=912793481162928208)

    await member.add_roles(standart_role)
#######################################################################


# !clear
@client.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def clear(ctx, amount=100):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount + 1)
#######################################################################


# !kick
@client.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await member.kick(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(f'кикнут грешник по имени {member.mention}')
#######################################################################


# !ban
@client.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await member.ban(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(
        f'Забанен грешник по имени {member.mention}. Он больше не будет мучать наш сервер своими грязными делишками как минимум 7 дней')
#######################################################################


time_window_milliseconds = 5000
max_msg_per_window = 5
author_msg_times = {}
# Struct:
# {
#    "<author_id>": ["<msg_time", "<msg_time>", ...],
#    "<author_id>": ["<msg_time"],
# }

@client.event
async def on_message(ctx):
    global author_msg_counts

    author_id = ctx.author.id
    curr_time = datetime.datetime.now().timestamp() * 1000

    if not author_msg_times.get(author_id, False):
        author_msg_times[author_id] = []

    author_msg_times[author_id].append(curr_time)

    expr_time = curr_time - time_window_milliseconds

    expired_msgs = [
        msg_time for msg_time in author_msg_times[author_id]
        if msg_time < expr_time
    ]

    for msg_time in expired_msgs:
        author_msg_times[author_id].remove(msg_time)


    if len(author_msg_times[author_id]) > max_msg_per_window:
        await ctx.send('Не спамь')


token = 'ты не спишешь мой токен'

client.run(token)```
````

Comment: В чём суть вопроса? Кому и почему что-то не нравитЬся?

Comment: Когда бот должен написать "Не спамь" вылазит ошибка в ctx.send('Не спамь')

Comment: Какая ошибка ?.

Comment: Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\Дискорд боты\Перепись бота\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\Дискорд боты\Перепись бота\main.py", line 85, in on_message
    await ctx.send.message('Не спамь')
AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'send'

Comment: А, ну вы зачем-то внутри функции `on_message` объект `message` обозвали объектом `ctx`. Замените `ctx` на `message` и отправляйте сообщения через `await message.channel.send(...)` как описано в примерах к документации https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for

Comment: Спасибо, работает

Answer (score 2):

Ну смотрите, вы зачем-то внутри функции `on_message` объект `message` обозвали объектом `ctx`. Замените `ctx` на `message` и отправляйте сообщения в канал, от куда поступил запрос, то есть через `await message.channel.send(...)`

Answer (score 1):

В ивент `on_message` передаётся `message`

 Из [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html) видим, чтобы вывести сообщение, нужно написать `message.channel.send`

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    global author_msg_counts

    author_id = message.author.id
    curr_time = datetime.datetime.now().timestamp() * 1000

    if not author_msg_times.get(author_id, False):
        author_msg_times[author_id] = []

    author_msg_times[author_id].append(curr_time)

    expr_time = curr_time - time_window_milliseconds

    expired_msgs = [
        msg_time for msg_time in author_msg_times[author_id]
        if msg_time < expr_time
    ]

    for msg_time in expired_msgs:
        author_msg_times[author_id].remove(msg_time)


    if len(author_msg_times[author_id]) > max_msg_per_window:
        await message.channel.send('Не спамь')
```